# Java - FontSizeAction for HTML JTextPane CSS

Tags: java, html, css, action, font-size

When using the code:

```
Action sizeAction = new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction(String.valueOf(size), size);
```

The button the action is assigned to inserts the HTML tags:

```
<FONT SIZE="5"> My text here </FONT>
```

This gives a very inaccurate scale of font size when I go to perform other functions. Instead what I want is to insert a style tag to change the font size with, e.g.

```
<FONT STYLE="font-size: 16pt;"> My text here </FONT>
```

How would I go about changing the TAGS that the FONTSIZE action inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to fix the problem! Just create a new Action and change the way attributes are added.

```
private class FontSizeAction extends HTMLEditorKit.FontSizeAction {
    private int size;

    public FontSizeAction(int size) {
        super("font-size-" + size, size);
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JEditorPane editor = getEditor(ae);
        if (size > 0) {
           MutableAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
           attr.addAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize, size + "pt");
           setCharacterAttributes(editor, attr, false);
        } else UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(editor);   
    }
}
```